# Error Truncated incorrect datetime value: '' in insert query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching data with the following query

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.time_spent , t1.goal FROM
                (SELECT temp_user_notes.user_id as user_id, temp_user_notes.activity_goal as goal, user_activities.activity_date as dates,
                date(now()) as activity_date, sum(user_activities.time_spent) as time_spent
                FROM temp_user_notes
                INNER JOIN user_activities
                ON temp_user_notes.user_id = user_activities.user_id
                WHERE activity_date = date(now())
                group by user_id, goal, dates,activity_date) as t1
                WHERE time_spent > goal ;
```

and it gives this result

```
 user_id time_spent   goal
    136       3000      0
    135       2000      5
```

but if i am trying to save this result in other table user_records then its giving me `Truncated incorrect datetime value: ''` error. Even though there is no datetime fields i am inserting

```
insert into user_records
 (user_id,
 goal,
 time_spent)


(SELECT 
t3.user_id, 
t3.goal, 
t3.time_spent
            FROM
            (SELECT t1.user_id, t1.time_spent , t1.goal,t1.activity_date FROM
            (SELECT temp_user_notes.user_id as user_id, temp_user_notes.activity_goal as goal, user_activities.activity_date as dates,
            date(now()) as activity_date, sum(user_activities.time_spent) as time_spent
            FROM temp_user_notes
            INNER JOIN user_activities
            ON temp_user_notes.user_id = user_activities.user_id
            WHERE activity_date = date(now())
            group by user_id, goal, dates,activity_date) as t1
            WHERE time_spent > goal);
```

Silly thing is if am trying to insert values through user_table them i am not having any date constraint error.

```
insert user_records (user_id,goal,time_spent)
            select id , activity_goal as goal, login_count as time_spent
            from users limit 1;
```

Comment: Do you have a date field in `user_records` that is configured to be `NOT NULL`  or some kind of constraint on it?

Comment: no i have only three fields in user_records user_id, time_spent, goal  there is no date field

Comment: The date functions you are using (datediff, datesub etc) should be against date fields, please could you check them if they are really dates or just strings you should parse before ?

Comment: @Gar but then it should give me some error while fetching the result also right? I am able to get result properly.

Comment: @Lannister i might be silly saying so, but the two queries do not look exactly the same, it might be intersting to copy the exact select part of your insert and run it (and not an equivalent one)

Comment: @gar your are right i actually made a copy paste mistake in posting question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Lannister you do not have to try insert a date type data to get the truncated error message,processing it as part of a formula will also yield this error if the sql mode configuration is such. Pls take Gar's advice and check the date fields in your source tables.

Comment: activity_date in user_activities table is of varchar type could that be problem? If so how can i parse it into datetype?